# Unable to import 'prettytable' in Python

Tags: python, prettytable

I have up top of my script "from prettytable import PrettyTable." However, I get an error stating, "Unable to import 'prettytable.'" I have downloaded prettytable-0.7 and placed it in the directory, but still get the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

You need do install the library (https://pypi.org/project/PrettyTable/) via pip, since you are using python3.7, use pip3.7

```
pip3.7 install prettytable
```

Then it should work

```
$ python3.7
>>> from prettytable import PrettyTable
>>>
```

Comment: I tried by installing pip which was successful, but I am still getting an invalid syntax.

Comment: Update the code in the question which shows invalid syntax

Comment: It states: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prettytable'

Comment: Are you using the same version of python which you used in pip?

Comment: Yes, Python 3.7.

Comment: I got it to work. I had to change where my file was and I put it in the prettytable folder.